# left outer join in LINQ

Tags: linq, join, left-join

how can i implement left outer join in following code:

```
var showmenu = from pag in pagerepository.GetAllPages()
               join pgmt in pagerepository.GetAllPageMeta()
               on pag.int_PageId equals pgmt.int_PageId 
               where (pag.int_OrganizationId == layoutrep.GetSidebarDetailById(SidebarDetailsId).int_OrganizationId
               && pag.int_PostStatusId == 2 && pag.bit_ShowInMenu == true) && 
               (pgmt.vcr_MetaKey.Contains("chk") && pgmt.vcr_MetaValue.Contains("true"))
               select pag;
```

Comment: You might also check out some samples on [Hooked on Linq](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx).  BTW, is this Linq to objects or do you need this to translate to a proper SQL query afterwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the key is the usage of the `DefaultIfEmpty()` operator. [Here is a good article](https://www.re-motion.org/blogs/mix/archive/2010/09/04/the-defaultifempty-linq-query-operator.aspx) that discusses usage of this operator in more detail.

```
var showmenu = from pag in pagerepository.GetAllPages()
               join pgmt in pagerepository.GetAllPageMeta() 
               on pag.int_PageId equals pgmt.int_PageId into leftj
           from pgmt2 in leftj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where (pag.int_OrganizationId == layoutrep.GetSidebarDetailById(SidebarDetailsId).int_OrganizationId
               && pag.int_PostStatusId == 2 && pag.bit_ShowInMenu == true) && 
               (pgmt2.vcr_MetaKey.Contains("chk") && pgmt2.vcr_MetaValue.Contains("true"))
               select pag;
```